# MySQL Errno 150 on VARCHAR fields

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, create-table

I'm getting an errno 150 when creating the following tables.  The first two work fine, but the third throws this error:

```
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'test2.exercise_type_exercise_groups' (errno: 150)
```

Any ideas?  I checked that the types, lengths, charset, and collation are identical for all key columns... What else could be the problem?

Thanks in advance for the help!

```
CREATE TABLE `exercise_groups` (
    `id` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY `pk_exercise_groups` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;

CREATE TABLE `exercise_types` (
    `id` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY `pk_exercise_types` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;

CREATE TABLE `exercise_type_exercise_groups` (
    `exercise_type` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `exercise_group` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `link_type` ENUM('primary', 'ancillary'),
    PRIMARY KEY `pk_exercise_type_exercise_groups` (`exercise_type`, `exercise_group`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_exercise_type_exercise_groups_exercise_type` 
        FOREIGN KEY (`exercise_type`) 
        REFERENCES `exercise_type` (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_exercise_type_exercise_groups_exercise_group` 
        FOREIGN KEY (`exercise_group`) 
        REFERENCES `exercise_group` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;
```

Comment: Oh geez, just noticed my reference is to a singular table name... I'm gonna try that and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem.  D'oh!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`errno 150` is a generic foreign key error that is rarely helpful.  There are at least four reasons this is the case:

1. The column types do not match
2. The column is not a key on the referenced table, or the referenced column/table does not exist (this was your problem; you had misspelled the other tables)
3. Any of the tables are not `InnoDB`.
4. You are trying to delete a foreign key that is not there.

Comment: @TheSmose I appreciate that; you can answer your own questions, but I think that SO answers should be helpful to anyone who views a question and not just for individual cases.

Comment: @Explosion Pills Thanks man, helped me out a lot, I was ready to make a post because all I could find on answers to this error where column types mismatched and with this answer I realized I had not set my StudentID in Students table to a primary key all good now. ALTER TABLE Enrolments
ADD FOREIGN KEY (StudentID)
REFERENCES Students(StudentID);